# iOS 7 Back Button Arrow Vertical Alignment

Tags: uibarbuttonitem, ios7, back-button, appearance

On iOS 7, is there any way to change the back button arrow's vertical alignment?  I can only change the vertical alignment of the title and nothing in UIBarButtonItem's appearance suggest that the arrow vertical alignment can be changed.

See the following example:

[image: example]

Comment: Can you give us some screenshots?

Comment: `[button setContentHorizontalAlignment:]` and `[button setContentVerticalAlignment:]` should do what you want. If you are directly accessing the `titleLabel` property to set the alignment, that will be your issue.

Comment: [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 10) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: The OP is looking to adjust the **arrow** position, not the title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to reach your goal is setting the `UINavigationBar`s `backIndicatorImage`to an arrow-image with space around it. You can mask your image, so the text is able to flow into parts of the image.

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = ...;

navigationBar.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Activity" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-image"];
navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-image-mask"];
```

AppCoda wrote a great article about customizing the `UINavigationBar`in iOS7. It's worth reading:
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

As the docs say you have to set **BOTH** properties to get this up and running: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uinavigationbar_class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/backIndicatorImage

Comment: You mean: "Hey Aaron". Ashley didn't ask this question